# How to calculate Vout in this resistors network?

Tags: voltage, calculator

How do I calculate Vout in terms of Vin and R1,...R5?

```
Vin----+-------+
       |       |
       R4      R1
       |       |
       +--R5---+--Vout
       |       |
       R3      R2
       |       |
       +---+---+
           |
          ///
```

Answer (score 3):

1. calculate Thevenin of R3/R4
2. calculate Thevenin of R3/R4 plus R5
3. claculate Thevenin of R1/R2
4. The output is the Thevenin of 2. and 3. (you only need the V, not the R)

Comment: Thanks @Wouter. Following your answer above, would this be correct:

   `code Vout = Vin * R1/(R1 + ((R3 || R4) + R5) || R2 ) ` 

By the way, this is not a school assignment. I didn't touch circuits for over 20 years, but now I am getting interested again.

Comment: Dunno. I can see the solution, but I am very bad at calculating. When I had to invert a 3 x 3 matrix on an exam, I did it 5 times, hoping for two identical answers....

Comment: Well, it seems the equation I put up is not correct. I think Vout should be 0.5 Vin when R5 is either zero Ohms or infinity Ohms. I get Vout =0.5 Vin when R5 is 0, but 0.75Vin when R5 is absent! So, I am still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't calculate the Thevenin equivalent of a resistor divider?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. it is easy to calculate Vout without R5 in the circuit as well as when it is shorted. But with R5 in place, I don't know how to calculate Vout.

Comment: I showed a 4 step sequence. Follow the steps, show the partial result after each step.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Inverting a matrix can be quite tricky. There are many things distracting your eyes. You think you're calculating a determinant but you end up calculating another.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, actually not just correct: it's also 
the best way to get the answer. The more detailed answer is:

Step 1: the Thevenin voltage is Vin*R3/(R3+R4)
          the Thevenin resistance is R3*R4/(R3+R4)

Step 2: the Thevenin resistance in step 1 is increased
          by R5

Step 3: the Thevenin voltage is Vin*R2/(R1+R2)
          the Thevenin resistance is R1*R2/(R1+R2)

```
   At this point, the simplified circuit, with
      new, shorter reference designators, is:

   VA = Vin*R3/(R3+R4) ---------+
                                |
                              R5+R3*R4/(R3+R4) = RA
                                |    
                                |
                                +-------Vout   
                                |
                                |
                              R1*R2/(R1+R2) = RB
                                |    
   VB = Vin*R2/(R1+R2) ---------+

   The output voltage, through superposition, is:

     VA*RB/(RA+RB) + VB*RA/(RA+RB) or (VA*RB+VB*RA)/(RA+RB)

   Norton fans would get the same result starting with

     (VA/RA + VB/RB)*RA*RB/(RA+RB)
```

Comment: We don't just give answers to homework problem here.  You might consider deleting this.  Note that Wouter provided the general approach, but left actually doing it to the student.

Comment: I'm familiar with the homework policy.  Note that the question was posed in 2011.